# Designing Chrome extension, stuck on Javascript implementation

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm attempting to design a Chrome extension that hotkeys "duplicate tab"; there's no reason for my designing this other than to gain experience in this specific area of coding so if there's already an extension out there that does this I'm not looking for that.

I have the basic idea of the manifest down, and am fairly close if not accurate on that. Javascript, though, is throwing me off completely. I did some research into callback functions, and am somewhat more informed, but it's still a very difficult process. I don't have enough information to debug.

My logic is thus: define a hotkey action in the manifest, listen for it in the background script. When it is recognized, execute the code (`chrome.tabs.duplicate(tabID)`). However, when I save the code, and use the extension either unpacked or packed in Chrome, the keyboard shortcut does nothing. I've attempted to change the shortcut to various inputs, I've restarted the browser and attempted packed and unpacked, I've brought up the details tab and no listener is identified in the menu, although my script appears to be running.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction? I've been working at this for a good 6 or 7 hours and can't seem to find a solution. Thanks in advance for any time or effort.

relevant code:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "author": "whims1",
    "name": "dupliTab",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Ctrl+Shift+F"
    },

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["duplicate.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ],

    "commands": {
        "toggle-feature-duplicate": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Ctrl+Shift+F",
                "mac": "Command+Shift+F"
            },
            "description": "Duplicate the active tab"
        },

        "_execute_browser_action": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "windows": "Ctrl+Shift+F",
                "mac": "Command+Shift+F",
                "chromeos": "Ctrl+Shift+F",
                "linux": "Ctrl+Shift+F"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

duplicate.js:

```
 chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
    loadRun();
});

function loadRun() {
    $.getScript("run.js");
    run();
}
```

run.js:

```
function run() {    
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true, currentWindow: true}, function(arrayOfTabs) {
        var currentTabId = arrayOfTabs[0].id;   
    });
    chrome.tabs.duplicate(currentTabId);
}
```

HTML popup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Popup</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>DupliTab</h1>
        <p>Press Ctrl+Shift+F to duplicate the active tab.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove _execute_browser_action, $.getScript("run.js"), embed run.js contents in the background script, use devtools debugger for the background page accessible from chrome://extensions page when [x] developer mode is checked.

Comment: Also read about asynchronous JavaScript if you haven't already because chrome API is asynchronous so the tab id won't be available outside of the query callback at the time you check it.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I was already using the background debugger which is how I knew the script was running but not working. Merging the two files makes sense; I'm actually not sure why I had them separate in the first place. It works now, glad my main issue was unfamiliarity with js